# How do get an html file to open in preferred html application from command line on linux?

Tags: browser, application, html, mime-types

How do get an html file to open in preferred application from command line on linux?

I have an xterm window open and an html file I want to do something like

```
open test.html
```

and that will start my preferred browser with the `test.html` file loaded.

(I'm looking for a solution that will work for any Linux desktop machine without me needing to know which browser app they have installed.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's OS/distribution/desktop-environment dependent, but in many places, you'll find a `xdg-open` command that does just that.

Comment: Thx that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

(see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=732285#p732285)

1.) save some webpage (via "File > Save page as"), e.g. as /tmp/somewebpage.html

2.) find out the media-type/filetype of this file:
`xdg-mime query filetype /tmp/site.html` (-> text/html)

2.) find the currently assigned default app for this filetype:
`xdg-mime query default text/html` (-> e.g.: brave.desktop)

3.) define the new default app for this filetype:
`xdg-mime default firefox.desktop text/html`

Look for ".desktop"-files, e.g. in:

```
/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
/usr/share/xfce4/helpers/firefox.desktop
```

An(other) Ubuntu/Debian(based) option (maybe this also works for html file, I currently cant verify)

`update-alternatives --get-selections` (to list apps and assigned command)
`update-alternatives --config ...` (insert an item from the list into "...", e.g.: editor)
`update-alternative --all` (interactively define selection for each option)

There is a gui-tool for that: GAlternatives (https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=galternatives)